# Java showing servers existance on client part (list)

Tags: java, networking

I want to develop network application (servers-clients) with some process:

- server creating instance on specific port and sending to other client in network information about existance (can be invitation message);
- clients are checking about existing servers in LAN network on specific port. Choose which one to connect and do other actions.

I tried `ServerSocket` and `Socket` and I know how to connect one server to one client. But to do procedures described above I need to do something like broadcating. Which method should I use and try? Is `MulticastServer` good for that one?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Sounds like JXSE may be something for you to look into: https://jxse.kenai.com/

Comment: Can i use only "standard" class to deal with my problem or should i go into jxse? Just asking :-)

Comment: Possibly, not sure. Just thought you may find that interesting, given that it's very similar to what you're trying to currently code at the moment.